# How do you assist target with a controller in FFXIV?

Tags: controllers, final-fantasy-14

How do you target the target of your current target (assist target) with a controller? The default keyboard/mouse key is <kbd>T</kbd>.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ha! Found a way!

Go to the **System configuration menu** > **Gamepad settings** and start **Button configuration**:

[image]

Then, select any button to bind **Assist target**, for example, Right Thumb-click:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, there currently isn't a button mapping to assist-target directly via controller.

However, the same can be accomplished via a macro, which can then be assigned to your cross hotbar:

- `/assist` (or `/as`) will assist your current target.
- `/assist "Player Name"` (or `/as "Player Name"`) will assist a player by name.
- `/assist <2>` (or `/as <2>`) will assist the party member in party slot 2. (Useful if you tend to re-order your party list to put, say, the main tank in a specific slot.) You can change the number to any other slot, as well.

Comment: Why a macro?  You can definitely set this directly in the options.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft If you know of a way to bind "assist target" to a controller button, then by all means, post an answer.

Comment: Due to Square-Enix's horrible, horrible support, I don't have access to the game anymore *(despite paying for a subscription)*, so I can't give specific instructions.  But I know this can be bound without a macro because I've done it.  It's under 'Targeting' in the keybind menu.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft On a keyboard, yes, absolutely. But with a controller, that'd be news to me.

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize the key-binding screens were different for the two.  My mistake, then.